# Параллакс эффект некорректно работает в ячейках tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, scrollview

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать параллакс эффект при скроллинге tableView, но почему-то все встает криво. Нужно, чтобы получился такой результат -

http://cl.ly/1n0C2e090s26

В итоге, у меня получается так.

https://gfycat.com/WillingPoisedIcelandgull

Использую для Autolayout фреймворк SnapKit
Соответственно, интерфейс строю без Storyboard'a

Вот мой код -

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
    for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [CategoryTableViewCell] {
        let x = cell.imageCategory.frame.origin.x
        let w = cell.imageCategory.bounds.width
        let h = cell.imageCategory.bounds.height
        let y = ((offsetY - cell.frame.origin.y) / h) * 25
        cell.imageCategory.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
    }
}
```

В классе `TableViewCell` выставляю `imageCategory.clipsToBounds = true`